# ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically (Account account, String authority, boolean sync) what does its second parameter mean?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I am trying to add events in calendar programmaticaly, events appear in the calendar application of android phone immediately but in google calendar they appear after some time, I want them to immediately appear in google calendar too.

I searched on net, and found a post which mentioned that "ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(Account account, String authority, boolean sync) function can help.

But I do not understand, what is the String authority? Documentation of ContentResolver says it is "the provider whose behavior is being controlled"....what does this mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Authority is the part just after type of uri. This is an identifier for contentprovider you want to query. 
In case of calendars, usually the uri for events will be

```
content://com.android.calendar/events/1
```

then Authority is `com.android.calendar`